# Unable to enable CORS in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, cors

I am running a Geoserver2.12 with tomcat7 in a container. I am trying to enable CORS inside the web.xml file of my geoserver installation but whenever I add these lines in the file:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and restart my tomcat then I am not able to access the geoserver (getting a 404) error. Any ideas what is causing this error?

[image]

Comment: which version of tomcat? Tomcat 7.0.55 works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363192/cors-tomcat-geoserver

Comment: #Mapperz This is my tomcat7 version: Tomcat7.0.39

Comment: backup your config/environment and install https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.55/bin/

Comment: An alternative to that? I am not root in this container.

Comment: you should be admin/sudo for changing this type of config.

Comment: Well I am able to make these changes but certainly not to install a newer version of tomcat. Actually the container managers informed me that this is the latest tomcat version they can provide. That sucks..

Comment: The first result from googling "[Tomcat CORS](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tomcat+CORS)" states (in the search results, you don't even have to click the link) "Apache Tomcat includes support for CORS (Starting from Tomcat version **7.0.41**)." - https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html

Comment: Well I was googling Geoserver CORS as the question states. But it makes sense what you say.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue - any other help on this @Luke?

Comment: @jotamon install tomcat 7.0.41 or later

Comment: Witnessing same symptoms with Tomcat 8.0.53